# Random swap of array elements- stack smashing detected

Tags: c

In my program to swap array elements randomly, value of j is determined as shown below:

```
    int j = rand() % (i+1);
```

Instead of (i+1), I tried using i, i+2 which returned valid output.
But for i+3 onward invalid outputs occur,sometimes with an error as:

```
    *** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can someone please explain why only a value less than 3 must be added?

Program code is as shown below:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    void swap (int *a, int *b)
    {
     int temp = *a;
     *a = *b;
     *b = temp;
    }
    void printArray (int arr[], int n)
    {
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     printf("%d ", arr[i]);
     printf("\n");
    }
    void randomize ( int arr[], int n )
    {
     srand ( time(NULL) );
     for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--)
         {
          int j = rand() % (i+1);
          swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
         }
    }
    int main()
    {
     int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
     int n = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);
     randomize (arr, n);
     printArray(arr, n);
     return 0;
    }
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: g++ did not give any error and ./a.out returns valid output so I had included this with c++ tag.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of (i+1), I tried using i, i+2 which returned valid output. But for i+3 onward invalid outputs occur

For anything greater than `i+1` (such as `i+2`, `i+3`, etc), the resulting index `j` from:

```
int j = rand() % (i+2);
```

might be, depending on what `rand()` returns, outside the bounds of the array `arr` and thus it could result in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

> Can someone please explain why only a value less than 3 must be added?

That's not correct conclusion, either. As said you can't add anything greater 1. It's so happens to "work" with 2 (as with anything undefined behaviour, you just can't rely on it and should avoid it).

You can print the value of `j` and see for yourself whether it could be outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your array has `n` elements in it, and the indexes of those elements range from `0` to `n-1`.

When you choose a new index with `rand() % (i+1)`, this results in a value from `0` to `i`.  Since `i` starts at `n-1` and goes down to `0`, this gives you an index that is in range.

If you use `rand() % (i+2)` for your random index, the resulting values range from `0` to `i+1`.  On the first iteration of the loop `i` is equal to `n-1`, which means you could get the value `n` as a result, which is out of the range of the array.

At this point, the problem can only occur on the first iteration, and only if the random value is `n`, so the chance if this happening is about 1 out of 9 runs so it won't happen all the time.  If you use `i+3`, the chance of going out of range doubles on the first iteration of the loop, plus it could happen on the next iteration.

The proper way to generate a random value here is `rand() % (i+1)`.  Anything larger than `i+1` risks going out of range, and the risk goes up the larger the value is.